# A course of pure mathematics example 1 - 5

Tags: calculus

The positive rational numbers may be arranged countably as the series $$1/1, 2/1, 1/2, 3/1, 2/2, 1/3, 4/1, 3/2, 2/3, 1/4,\dots$$
Show that $p/q$ is the $$[1/2(p+q-1)(p+q-2)+q]^{\text{th}},$$ term of the series.
I can't understand why I should add $q$ and why add $p+q$. Let $t = p+q$. Then the first term is $t = 2$, the second term is $t = 3$, the third term is also $t=3$, etc. How can I show this?

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: If $t = p+q$ then $1 + 1 + 2+3 + 4+ ...... + (t-2)\mapsto \frac {t-1}1$.  Can you show that?  And then $(1 + 1 + 2+3 + 4+ ...... + (t-2)) + (t-1)\mapsto \frac {t-q}q$.  *That's why you must add the $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the fractions (not the rationals because we don't insist that they be in lowest terms.  We get things equal to $\frac 12$ many times) are arranged by increasing $p+q$.  First we have $\frac 11$ with $p+q=2.$  Next we have the two fractions with $p+q=3$ and so on.  If you look at the triangular numbers the last fraction for a given $p+q$ is in position $\frac 12(p+q-1)(p+q)$  Now they are in order of increasing $q$.

Answer (score 0):

It's just detail.

The simple idea is you can group them:

$[\frac 11], [\frac 21, \frac 12], [\frac 31, \frac 22, \frac 13], [ \frac 41, \frac 32, \frac 23, \frac 14], ...., $

And because Homo Sapiens Sapiens have brains wiht large surface area folding, we can recognize the pattern.  We can recognize the pattern even if we can't immediately put it into words.  The pattern is "....um, well, you see you start of with $2$ and you do the numbers that add up to $2$ to and that's $1+1$ and ... well, that's it so you put $\frac 11$.  And then you do $3$ and you do the numbers that add up to three and that's $2+1$ and $1+2$ and so you start with the larger one on top and work down and do $\frac 21$ and $\frac 12$ and the for $4$ you have three of them them $3+1, 2+2, 1+3$ and so... you  get it right, and because we can list them that all match up the regualar counting numbers so ... $\frac mn$ would be in the group where $N = m+n$ and we'll there's got to be some formula...."

So now it's just busy work to get the formula:

$1\mapsto \frac 11$ (that's the first of the group that add to $2$)

$2\mapsto \frac 21$ (that's the first of the group that adds to $3$)

$4\mapsto \frac 31$ (that's the first of the group that adds to $4$)

$7\mapsto \frac 41$ (that's the first of the group that adds to $5$)

... and so on....

er... what?  Just how so on?

$k \mapsto \frac {n-1}1$ (that's the first of the group that adds to $N$)

Exactly how do we get there??

Well, each group gets one higher.

So $1\mapsto $ the group that add to $ 2$.

$1+ 1=2\mapsto $ the group that add to $ 3$

$1+1+2=4\mapsto $ the group that add to $ 4$

$1+ 1 + 2 + 3 = 7\mapsto $ the group that add to $ 5$

.... so ...

$1 + 1+ 2+ 3+ ......+ (N-2)\mapsto $ the group that add to $ N$

So what gets mapped to $\frac pq$?

Well....$\frac pq$ is in the group that adds to $p + q$.

And the group that adds to $p + q$ is $\frac {p+q-1}{1}, \frac {p+q-2}{2}, ..... , \frac 1{p+q - 1}$.

And $\frac {p}{q} = \frac {p+q -q}q$ is the $q$th term in the group.

So

$1 + 1+ 2+ ....... + (p+q-2)\mapsto \frac {p+q -1}1$ then very first term of the group.

So

$(1 + 1+2+ ...... + (p+q-2)) + (q-1)\mapsto $ the $q$th term of the group: $\frac pq$.

So $(1 + 1 + 2 + ....... + (p+q-2)) + (q-1) =$

$(1 + 2 + ...... + (p+q-2)) + 1 + (q-1) =$

$\frac {(p+q -2)(p+q-)}2 + q\mapsto \frac pq$.

....

Try in.

What maps to $\frac 32$.  Well, that the group that adds to $5$ so we must go past that groups that add to $2, 3,4$ which have $1,2,3$ members each so we go past $1+ 2+3=6$ to get $7\mapsto \frac 41$, the first of the group.  But this is that the second of the group so it is $8\mapsto \frac 32$ and indeed: $p = 3; q=2$ and $\frac {(3+2 - 2)(3+2 -1)}2 + 2 = 8$.

Comment: Wow. it is the best explanation I've never seen before. Thanks a lot